# Is there a way to change the formatting of the labels of a time graph in echarts?

Tags: javascript, time, charts, data-analysis, echarts

I am working with the [echarts library](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) and I have to compute data that has timestamps. The library automatically spits out the time as the labels of the time axis, but I would love to change this to the elapsed time between each timestamps. Is there a way to do this?

An example would be something like the [this](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-gradient). Is it possible to change the output date to something like "5 days ago", "7 days ago", etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of Echarts components have a formatter to change the format of the data they display. Here you can use the one from `xAxis.axisLabel` ([doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.formatter)) :

```js
axisLabel: {
  formatter: function (params) {
    var daysAgo = (new Date(now) - new Date(params)) / 86400000
    return daysAgo + " days ago"
  }
}
```

Full code from your example :

```js
// prettier-ignore
const now = "2000-07-24"
const data = [["2000-06-05", 116], ["2000-06-06", 129], ["2000-06-07", 135], ["2000-06-08", 86], ["2000-06-09", 73], ["2000-06-10", 85], ["2000-06-11", 73], ["2000-06-12", 68], ["2000-06-13", 92], ["2000-06-14", 130], ["2000-06-15", 245], ["2000-06-16", 139], ["2000-06-17", 115], ["2000-06-18", 111], ["2000-06-19", 309], ["2000-06-20", 206], ["2000-06-21", 137], ["2000-06-22", 128], ["2000-06-23", 85], ["2000-06-24", 94], ["2000-06-25", 71], ["2000-06-26", 106], ["2000-06-27", 84], ["2000-06-28", 93], ["2000-06-29", 85], ["2000-06-30", 73], ["2000-07-01", 83], ["2000-07-02", 125], ["2000-07-03", 107], ["2000-07-04", 82], ["2000-07-05", 44], ["2000-07-06", 72], ["2000-07-07", 106], ["2000-07-08", 107], ["2000-07-09", 66], ["2000-07-10", 91], ["2000-07-11", 92], ["2000-07-12", 113], ["2000-07-13", 107], ["2000-07-14", 131], ["2000-07-15", 111], ["2000-07-16", 64], ["2000-07-17", 69], ["2000-07-18", 88], ["2000-07-19", 77], ["2000-07-20", 83], ["2000-07-21", 111], ["2000-07-22", 57], ["2000-07-23", 55], ["2000-07-24", 60]];
const dateList = data.map(function (item) {
  return item[0];
});
const valueList = data.map(function (item) {
  return item[1];
});
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var option = {
  // Make gradient line here
  visualMap: [
    {
      show: false,
      type: 'continuous',
      seriesIndex: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 400
    },
    {
      show: false,
      type: 'continuous',
      seriesIndex: 1,
      dimension: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: dateList.length - 1
    }
  ],
  title: [
    {
      left: 'center',
      text: 'Gradient along the y axis'
    },
    {
      top: '55%',
      left: 'center',
      text: 'Gradient along the x axis'
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      data: dateList,
      axisLabel: {
        formatter: function (params) {
          var daysAgo = (new Date(now) - new Date(params)) / 86400000
          return daysAgo + " days ago"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      data: dateList,
      gridIndex: 1
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {},
    {
      gridIndex: 1
    }
  ],
  grid: [
    {
      bottom: '60%'
    },
    {
      top: '60%'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      showSymbol: false,
      data: valueList
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      showSymbol: false,
      data: valueList,
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      yAxisIndex: 1
    }
  ]
};

myChart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```